# Simplify $F(x) = \exp[-\ln^2x^h]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I was wondering if the expression $F(x) = \exp[-\ln^2x^h]$ can be simplified even further? As you can see, the $\ln$ which is the natural logarithmic function is raised (and not its argument) to power of $2$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could write it as $\exp(-h^2(\ln x)^2)$, but that's about it. Writing $x^{-h^2\ln x}$ wouldn't be as natural.

Comment: I was thinking that probably the properties of inverse functions may be useful (e.g. Exp[Ln[X]]=X).

Comment: Yes, that's why I said $x^{-h^2\ln x}$, but you've got two $\ln x$s being multiplied so that's not useful in the end.